# Visual Basic Edit Tar Archive

Tags: vb.net, vb6, tar

Is it possible for vb to extract files from tar(and put them back)? I found [this](http://www.example-code.com/vb/untar.asp) but it says that

```
Dim tar As New ChilkatTar  <<<< ChilkatTar does not exist
```

I am trying to edit one xml file(which is not compressed) but if i do that with notepad, the tar becomes corrupt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- [ChilkatTar](http://www.chilkatsoft.com/tar-dotnet.asp) is a commercial component that you'd need to purchase, you can find it here:
- [7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) supports unpacking and packing TAR files and is free so you could probably execute the command line version of it from your app to do the packing/unpacking. 
  It is also open-source, so you might even be able to copy the source into a library to use from your own application if you prefer, assuming that its license is compatible with your needs.